# Extract predefined phrases in array from string in PHP

Tags: php

```
$phrases = array(
    "New York", "New Jersey", "South Dakota", 
    "South Carolina", "Computer Repair Tech"
);
$string = "I live in New York, but used to live in New Jersey working as a " .
    "computer repair tech.";
```

Extract `$phrases` found in `$string`

`$new_string` output should be: `New York New Jersey Computer Repair Tech`

Comment: What have you tried? This is quite straightforward to do, or at least to get pretty close to.

Comment: So what have you tried? Googled it?

Comment: I've googled it but have only managed to find solutions for extracting individual words, can't seem to find a solution for extracting phrases that contain multiple words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use stripos (for best efficiency): http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php. Your code would be something like the following:

```
$matches = array();
foreach($phrases as $phrase) {
    if(stripos($string,$phrase) !== false){
        $matches[] = $phrase;
    }
}

$new_string = implode(" ",$matches);
```

as with Davo's answer stripos will give you a case insensitive search

Answer (score 3):

```
 $new_string = "";  

 foreach($phrases as $p) {

      $pos = stripos($string, $p);
      if ($pos !== false) {
         $new_string .= " ".$p;
       }
 }
 $new_string = trim($new_string);  // to remove additional space at the beginnig

echo $new_string;
```

note, that your find will be case-insensitive , if you wanna be case-sensitive search 
use `strpos()`  instead of `stripos`

Comment: This seems to be introducing an extra unnecessary step. We already have our phrase, why bother with the substring? Also what happens here if $pos is false (strpos returns false if there are no matches).

Comment: `stripos`, actually, because there's a difference in casing. Also, the original string is already in `$p`, so there is no need for the `substr()` call, which would make it a bit faster.

Comment: This will also precede the string with a space, which is why I imploded an array in my answer. To do it this way, you would also want to use trim on the string to remove unnecessary whitespace

Comment: right, did not take that into account, added it, but yours seems better +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
$phrases = array("New York", "New Jersey", "South Dakota", "South Carolina", "Computer Repair Tech");
$string = ("I live in New York, but used to live in New Jersey working as a computer repair tech.");

$matches = stringSearch($phrases, $string);

var_dump($matches);


function stringSearch($phrases, $string){
    $phrases1 = trim(implode('|', $phrases));
    $phrases1 = str_replace(' ', '\s', $phrases1);

    preg_match_all("/$phrases1/s", $string, $matches);

    return implode(' ', $matches[0]);
}
```